# Keep Xcode terminal from disappearing

Tags: xcode, terminal

For some reason when I build/run my code in Xcode, the terminal pane automatically disappears and I have to use Ctrl+Shift+C to get it back. This can be frustrating when you're compiling often. Does anyone know how to make it stay put?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Link's answer is for Xcode 3, I think.

For Xcode 4, open the Behaviors tab in Preferences.... and under "Build Starts" (make sure that's checked", enable the "Show" debugger with "Console View" section.

[image: Xcode4 Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

'Preferences' -> 'Behaviours' -> Under 'Running' -> 'Completes' -> Change 'If no output, hide debugger' to 'Show debugger'

Answer (score 0):

go to xcode preferences, under building. Build Results Window , Open duing builds. set to Always

Comment: Thanks Link, but I don't see that in the preferences. Maybe that was in another version?